# MySQL group by calculated field

Tags: mysql

I have members that have to pay for their membership. And I store: payment date, and membership length (they can pay for 1 month or several).

Now I'd like to know which payments are overdue, or soon to be.

My logic was: get an expiration date for each membership (last payment date + membership length) and then just look at the highest value of that for each member.

Here's my query, but I did want to explain my reasoning, as you may want to question that or even the format of the DB (but please don't ask me to store the expiration date).

```
SELECT tbl.company AS company,
       MAX(ADDDATE( paydate, INTERVAL paylength MONTH ))) AS expiration,
       tbl.id
FROM tblPayments
JOIN tbl ON tblPayments.comp_id = tbl.id
GROUP BY expiration
ORDER BY expiration ASC
```

I've read that grouping by calculated fields may not be possible, but my knowledge of MySQL is not strong enough to understand the workarounds. I'd appreciate any help you can provide! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try putting the entire expression in the group by clause, rather than the alias: `GROUP BY MAX(ADDDATE( paydate, INTERVAL paylength MONTH )))` ... it seems I got something like that to work once when the alias wouldn't ... I haven't tested; it's just a thought ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are grouping by the aggregated result of your group which is not possible and not what you intended. Based on your explanation I would think you are trying to do this

```
SELECT 
    tbl.company AS company, 
    MAX(ADDDATE( paydate, INTERVAL paylength MONTH )) AS expiration,
    tbl.id 
FROM tblPayments 
JOIN tbl 
    ON tblPayments.comp_id = tbl.id 
GROUP BY tbl.company , tbl.id 
HAVING expiration < NOW()
ORDER BY expiration ASC
```

And @dleiftah brings up a good point, you cannot always use the alias although MySQL seems to let you in a `GROUP BY` whereas MSSQL never does. I forget exactly when...